# comparación de posiciones de un arreglo en c#

Tags: c#

Podrían apoyarme:

En la imagen muestro el llenado de un gridView con datos que traigo en un Arreglo de una BD, necesito comparar que de la fechas que se muestran en el GridView no sean '2017-07-01', si alguna de la fechas coincide con esta cadena debo mostrar un mensaje que diga que la fecha es errónea.
mi Código es el siguiente para el llenado del Griview

```
  arrRep = oRep.buscarTodosImpo(dFecIni, dFecFin, nEjecutivoSel2);
                    gReporteExpo.DataSource = arrRep;
                    gReporteExpo.DataBind();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencillo si sabes lo que hay dentro de arrRepo puedes usar LINQ para buscar y basado en el resultado que te de puedes mostrar el error o seguir la ejecución de tu programa.

```
arrRep = oRep.buscarTodosImpo(dFecIni, dFecFin, nEjecutivoSel2);
//Asumiendo que la propiedad que quieres buscar para comparar sea FechaArribo y sea de tipo String
var count = arrRepo.Where(it => it.FechaArribo == "2017-07-01").Count();
/* Sino si es de tipo Fecha puedes hacer dos cosas 
   Llevar a cadena la fecha o llevar a fecha la cadena
    it => it.FechaArribo == DateTime.parse("2017-07-01")
   o
    it => String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",it.FechaArribo.Year,it.FechaArribo.Month,it.FechaArribo.Day).Equals("2017-07-01")
   Esta ultima es la que recomiendo para que funcione bien en caso de almacenar la hora tambien en FechaArribo */

if(count == 0){
    gReporteExpo.DataSource = arrRep;
    gReporteExpo.DataBind();
}
else{
  //Muestro el error
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias :) me funciono.

Comment: disculpa intento mostrar en un mensaje las referencias las cuales tienen la fecha '2017-01-01', utilizo este código  pero no muestra nada, es correcto esto ?
     `var q = (from f in arrRep
                                     where f.Arribo == "2017-01-01" || f.Revalidacion == "2017-01-01" || f.Previo == "2017-01-01" || f.Desadua == "2017-01-01" || f.EnvioFact == "2017-01-01"                                         select f).ToArray();`